# I'm using sap.m.Wizard. But the number of steps aren't dynamically rendered

Tags: sapui5

I'm trying to create a wizard using sap.m.wizard in which the number of steps can be dynamically rendered. 
I'm unsure on how to proceed with this.

flow can be:
1-2-3-4-5
1-3-4-5
1-2-4-5
1-3-5

Problem I'm facing:
When we create the wizard dynamically,
if we click on item with 5 steps .. OKAY
Then we click on item with 7 steps .. OKAY
Then we click on item with 6 steps .. ERROR
"dynamic step removal not yet supported"

Comment: can you provide what you've got so far? assume you are either adding steps manually within your controller or binding the sap.m.Wizard steps aggregation to an array in your model?

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
wizard.removeAllSteps();            
wizard.addStep(step1);
wizard.addStep(step2);
wizard.addStep(step3);
wizard.addStep(step4);
wizard.discardProgress(wizard.getSteps()[0]);
```

You can choose which step you want to add in which order. This will work for you.